# Start 0,0 centered spiral from an arbitrary point

Tags: c, algorithm, spiral

I am trying to make a spiral centred in (0,0) that you can start form any arbitry point inside it.

In other words: the spiral should have the shape of one that started at 0,0 but starting from an arbitrary point (as if you removed previous positions)

I made the following code but it only works when both initX and initY are 0:

```
void printSpiralCoords(int32_t initX, int32_t initY, uint32_t steps) {

    int8_t dx = 0;
    int8_t dy = 0;

    uint32_t stepsDone = 0;
    uint32_t length = 0;

    uint32_t absX = abs(initX);
    uint32_t absY = abs(initY);


    if (absX > absY) {
        if (initX >= 0) {
            dy = 1;
        }
        else {
            dy = -1;
        }
        stepsDone = absY;
        length = absX;
    }
    else {
        if (initY >= 0) {
            dx = 1;
        }
        else {
            dx = -1;
        }
        stepsDone = absX;
        length = absY;
    }

    if (length == 0) {
        length = 1;
    }


    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < steps; i++) {

        printf("x: %d, z: %d\n", initX, initY);

        initX += dx;
        initY += dy;

        stepsDone++;
        if (stepsDone >= length) {
            stepsDone = 0;
            if (dx == 0) {
                dx = -dy;
                dy = 0;
                length++;
            }
            else {
                dy = dx;
                dx = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rules:

- Spiral should always turn left
- You cannot build from 0,0 every time and "ignore" previous blocks
- Sice `steps` variable can be up to 2^32-1 cannot use lookup table

Here is an example on how it should work:
Starting at (0,0):

[image]

Starting at (0,1):

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: Hint: look carefully at co-ordinates of 4 diagonals radiating from (0,0). Notice the characteristics of "sum", "sign" and "equality" and the effect on the direction to the next cell. To avoid an infinite loop, which diagonal 'triggers' incrementing to the next "orbit" distance? Advice: move the determination of "turning" (always left in your example) to a function that only cares about relationships of the current coord values, and is indifferent to their magnitude.

Comment: Why is it supposed to -1,-1 instead of 0,0 from -1,0???

Comment: Because, as you can see in the first image,  0,0 is already visited

Comment: Hint #2: If you've written something that works from (0,0), a wasteful but effective solution is to silently generate coordinates until you reach the desired "starting point", then begin reporting for as many more as the user wants from that "initial location"... Recognise that cells come in 8 "flavours" (corner transitions * 4 + next up/down/left/right). Deducing the category of an arbitrary location is possible, but would be messy...

Comment: As I added this morning siliently generating coordinates from 0,0 is not an option. This is because performance is very relevant and numbers can grow a lot

Comment: My apologies for not spotting the added details... Still, _seeing_ how to recognise a cell's "category" as being one of 4 diagonals ("corners" to "turn" at, except lower right that extends the orbit) or one of 4 "wedges" between the diagonal radiating from (0,0) will indicate how to proceed from any given initial cell... Draw and label at least one more "orbit" to see how the relationship of any cell's col & row values can be translated to "how to advance to the next cell in the series". There are 8 categories to be handled...

Comment: The direction to next from current is depends on the current position only, and it can be solved arithmetic(few if-else code). Consider the direction for each position directly; No need to considering "turn".

Comment: For example, Looking the result of painting cells in different 4 colors according to the next direction, may be your help.

Comment: In your first image, it seems that the sequence `{0,0}, {0,1}, {-1,1}....)` is equally valid as the one that is shown. In fact, from `{0,0}`, you could go in ***any*** direction for the first move, and still make a left-turning spiral. Is there some rule that governs the first step when there are multiple choices?

Comment: No, there is no rules to govern the first step, it just need to be consistent across all spirals

Comment: Another way to view this is that you always want to go counterclockwise around the origin. The vector from point (x, y) to the origin is (−x, −y), and a vector pointing counterclockwise 90° from that is (−y, +x). So you want the choice of a unit vector right, up, left, or down that is closest to (−y, +x). However, I do not see a good way to compute that, besides my existing answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be stated as: Given a point (*x*, *y*) in the sequence, determine the next point in the sequence, and the points after that.

The sequence consists of intervals of moving right, then moving up, then moving left, then moving down, and repeating. The turns largely occur on the diagonal lines *y* = *x* and *y* = −*x*. Therefore, we can determine which way to move based on comparison with those lines, with some care about exactly where the transitions occur:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct { int32_t x, y; } Point;


static Point Next(Point a)
{
    //  If we are on or left of y = x and right of y = -x, move left.
    if (a.x <= a.y && -a.x < a.y)
        return (Point) { a.x-1, a.y };

    //  If we are on or below y = -x and above y = x, move down.
    if (a.y <= -a.x && a.x < a.y)
        return (Point) { a.x, a.y-1 };

    //  If we are on or right of y = x and on or left of y = -x, move right.
    if (a.y <= a.x && a.y <= -a.x)
        return (Point) { a.x+1, a.y };

    //  Otherwise, move up.
    else
        return (Point) { a.x, a.y+1 };
}


int main(void)
{
    Point a = { 0, 0 };

    printf("(%" PRId32 ", %" PRId32 ")\n", a.x, a.y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        a = Next(a);
        printf("(%" PRId32 ", %" PRId32 ")\n", a.x, a.y);
    }
}
```

Then reorganizing the comparisons can give us:

```
static Point Next(Point a)
{
    //  Are we above-right of y = -x?
    if (-a.x < a.y)

        /*  If we are also on or below-left of y = x, move left.
            Otherwise, move up.
        */
        return a.x <= a.y ? (Point) { a.x-1, a.y } : (Point) { a.x, a.y+1};

    //  Otherwise, we are on or below-left of y = -x.
    else

        /*  If we are also  above-left of y = x, move down.
            Otherwise, move right.
        */
        return a.x < a.y ? (Point) { a.x, a.y-1 } : (Point) { a.x+1, a.y };
}
```

Comment: While this does work I don't like it that much because of the need to recalculate every time where you are. As said in the post performance is relevant here. If I get no other way of doing it I might take this route

Comment: @Dioswison: Given the next step, you can easily plan how many steps it is to the next turn and enter a pattern for computing further steps. You might enter another question for that, but it is a fairly simple programming task you should do yourself rather than asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is not complicated, I ended up doing it similar to the other guy (which is basically what I was doing originally) and it wasn't dificult. I guess I wan't on my best mental state for the 2 days I tried to do this before

Comment: @Dioswison If you want to talk about "performance", post your original "works correctly but slow" code when you first post the question.

Comment: @fana When I posted the question I did not have a working example, best I had was what I posted. I managed to expand that solution after reading the answers and thinking a bit more

Comment: @Dioswison Ah, ok, now I understand this question is  just "please debug `if-else` part in this my code" (not about "how to").

Comment: It was a how to, I thought that what I was doing was wrong. I do consider this as a valid answer(I upvoted it), but not a perfect one, that is the reason of my "performance" claim

Answer (score 1):

At init you can use some statement to know where you are in the spiral :

```
if (x > 0 && x == y) // your top right

else if (x <= 0 && x == y) // your bottom left or 0, 0

else if (x < 0 && x * -1 == y) // your top left

else if (x > 0 && (x - 1) * -1 == y) // your bottom right

else if (x < 0 && ...) // left side (figure you that one by yourself)

else if (x > 0 && ...) // right side (figure you that one by yourself)

else if (y < 0 && ...) // bottom side (figure you that one by yourself)

else if (y > 0 && ...) // top side (figure you that one by yourself)
```

After you can use that knowledge to step in the spiral.

Comment: My main issue is not determining the direction, but for how long do I need to keep it

Comment: Nvm, already got it. If you add that logic I will mark your answer as correct, if not I'll post one myself